# Cocoa - Draw image from binary string

Tags: cocoa, spotify

Iam trying to draw a TIFF image from a string in XCode to display it in the dock.
The TIFF-image is obtained through an AppleScript that interacts with Spotify:

```
tell application "Spotify"
set aTrackArtwork to artwork of current track
end tell
```

The string that I receive is something like this:

```
TIFF4D4D002A00041EB821585D22595E215..
```

How can I draw an image from this binary code? My current code (which is a proof-of-concept) looks like this:

```
NSImage *myImage = [[NSImage alloc] init];
myImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"ikoner"];
[NSApp setApplicationIconImage:myImage];
```

Is there any way to draw the image within the myImage object?

And, is there any easier way to obtain this information directly in my Xcode project without having to rely on the applescript?

My goal is to create a simple application that gets the current playing song and display it's album art in the dock.

I appreciate all answers that may or may not lead me closer to the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simply with the Scripting Bridge.

First, generate `Spotify.h` in the Terminal:

```
sdef /Applications/Spotify.app | sdp -fh --basename Spotify
```

Then, import the header file into your project, then link to `ScriptingBridge.framework`.

Finally, grab the image and put it in the Dock. Here's a basic example:

```
#import "Spotify.h"

// Get the image from Spotify
SpotifyApplication *spotify = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.spotify.client"];
NSImage *coverArt = spotify.currentTrack.artwork;

// Create an image view and put it in the Dock
NSImageView *imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
imageView.image = coverArt;

NSDockTile *dock = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] dockTile];
dock.contentView = imageView;
[dock display];
```

Comment: I completely forgot about this post, but this is exactly what I did, and it works great! I was not aware of the ScriptingBridge, but Apples documentation brought me up to speed. Perhaps it was a good thing I did not saw this post until now, I learnt a whole lot from reading the documentation. Thanks for a very good reply, I'll mark yours as the solution!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not to familiar with the Spotify api, however something like this seems like it would work (convert your string into an NSData object:

```
[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:]
```

Comment: I've tried to look into that, that made the most sense. I quitted reading the documentation because I thought I was "way out". It might do the trick though. Iam a little bit unsure how to use NSData objects, but I'll look into it! Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I came across something quite marvelous. The Apple Scripting Bridge. Long story short, I seem to get the artwork as NSImages directly. I'll post an answer as soon as I figure this one out. I've been missing out some superb developer love from Apple!